# Identifying the id of the clicked tab on Jquery Slider tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have 2 outer tabs and each outer tab has 2 inner tabs and these 2 inner tabs have 2 links. The outer tabs are in the class flip and the inner tabs are in the class panel. When flip is clicked, panel is expanded to show the contents of the tab. On what I have done, when I click any of the outer tabs, all the outer tabs are slid and the inner tabs that are direct child of the outer tabs also slide, revealing all the links. But what I want to achieve is, when an outer tab is clicked, only it has to be slid, revealing the inner tabs and when an Inner tab is clicked, make only the links that belong to that clicked inner tab should be revealed.

HTML :

```
<div class="flip" id="outer_flip_1">Outer 1
     <div class="panel" id="outer_panel_1">
          <div class="flip" id="link_flip_1"> Panel 1
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_1"> Link 1 </div>
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_2"> Link 2 </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip" id="link_flip_2"> Panel 2
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_3"> Link 3 </div>
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_4"> Link 4 </div>
          </div>
     </div>
<div class="flip" id="outer_flip_2">Outer 2
     <div class="panel" id="outer_panel_2">
          <div class="flip" id="link_flip_3"> Panel 3
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_5"> Link 5 </div>
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_6"> Link 6 </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flip" id="link_flip_4"> Panel 4
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_7"> Link 7 </div>
              <div class="panel" id="link_panel_8"> Link 8 </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(evt){
    $(".flip").click(function(evt){
    $(".panel").stop().slideToggle(300);
    });
 });
 </script>
```

CSS:

```
   .panel,.flip
   {
       padding:5px;
       text-align:center;
       border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;    
   }
   .flip
   {
    background-color:#e5eecc;
   }
   .panel
   {
      display:none;
      background-color:#fff;
   }
```

Comment: Is below given solution will work for you or need to update the code?

Comment: I just stepped out. I will check it in 30 minutes. Sorry.

Comment: no problem, let me know if you facing issue again after this code

Answer (score 0):

By default all tabs will be display none like set display none in css to panel and flip both and apply below given code it will work because it's consist of current object.
Please try below js code

```
 $(document).ready(function(evt){
    $(".flip").click(function(evt){
    $(this).slideToggle(300);
    });
$(".panel").click(function(evt){
    $(this).slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is your need exactly please